# At which colatitude $\theta$ is the error between $\vec g_{eff}$ and $\vec g$ maximum?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, newtonian-gravity, earth, centrifugal-force

Suppose a plumb bob hangs without swinging, then the string defines the
effective direction of gravity. Suppose you are holding the bob on the surface of the
earth at colatitude $\theta$, where $\theta$ measures the spherical angle as measured from the north pole, then the error $\epsilon$ between $\vec g_{eff}$ and $\vec g$ is given by

$$\epsilon \approx \frac{R \Omega^2 sin(\theta) cos(\theta)}{g-R \Omega^2 sin^2(\theta)}$$

We can find the maximum error, by differentiating $\epsilon$ with respect to $\theta$. I was curious just if we can answer this question conceptually.

Comment: It seems the denominator with $R\Omega$ has not correct units ?

Comment: @ Cretin2 good catch, I have corrected it. Thanks!

Comment: The easiest way is to graph the function, no?  And you only need a domain of 0 to 2pi.

Comment: If you think that amount of calculation is tedious, just wait until you learn E&M or Quantum.

Comment: @ Michael Seifert, experienced that in E&M already haha. I was just curious if there is a way to conceptually answer this.

Comment: Sea level on the real earth is not a sphere. Rather it’s the shape that everywhere sets this error to zero.

Comment: @ Bob Jacobsen can you elaborate on that a bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will define $\alpha \equiv R\Omega^2/g$ so that we can write
$$
\epsilon = \frac{\alpha\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)}{1-\alpha\sin^2(\theta)}.
$$
We can differentiate this using the quotient rule to find that
$$
\frac{d\epsilon}{d\theta} = \frac{\alpha(1-\alpha\sin^2(\theta))(\cos^2(\theta)-\sin^2(\theta)) + 2\alpha^2\sin^2(\theta)\cos^2(\theta)}{(1-\alpha\sin^2(\theta))^2};
$$
this requires a little work but isn't too tedious. Setting $d\epsilon/d\theta = 0$ to find the maximum $\theta$, we get (after some algebra)
$$
(1-\alpha)\tan^2(\theta_{\rm max}) = 1 \implies \theta_{\rm max}=\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{1-\alpha}}\right).
$$
Note that this implies the constraint $\alpha < 1$, or $R\Omega^2 < g$.